# How to link selenium standalone docker container properly with host networking?

Tags: python, selenium, docker, docker-network

I'm running two docker containers as follows:

one is for [selenium/standalone-chrome](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/tree/master/StandaloneChrome)

```sh
$ docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/standalone-chrome
```

and the main container uses host networking to connect to MySQL which is running on localhost

```sh
$ docker run --rm --network="host" $(IMAGE_REPO)
```

but when I tried to initiate the driver in the main container

```py
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub', 
                desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
```

I got error message which is either

`urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))`

or

`urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))`

did I forget anything / any parameters when trying to establish the containers? or the value passing to `command_executor` should not be `'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub'`?

I also tried to use docker bridge networking, but then I have no idea how to connect to MySQL server on localhost

```py
SQLALCHEMY_URI = '{driver}://{user}:{pwd}@{host}/{db}?charset=utf8' \
.format(
    driver='mysql+pymysql',
    host='127.0.0.1:3306',
    user='root',
    pwd='0000',
    db='default'
)
```

Comment: Check permission of the user that executes the script.

Comment: Which version of OS you are using? Have your tried `command_executor=localhost:4444/wd/hub`?

Comment: @Light.G I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 running on VirtualBox with bridged adapter. I did try `localhost` but it ended in the same result. More information here: The Dockerfile of the image only has `ENTRYPOINT ["python", "main.py"]` and If I firstly run bash with the main container, and execute the same python file, there's no problem at all. But it fails if I directly run the container.

Answer (score 0):

Update the following libraries in your Dockerfile:

Set Selenium library version to 3.3.1 (selenium==3.3.1).

i.e: Make use of a Selenium image, whose version is 3.3.1.

Use **selenium/node-chrome:3.3.1** instead of **selenium/node-chrome:3.141.59-gold**